# SpriteKit issue with zPosition

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am encountering an issue with the zPosition of nodes on my SpriteKit scene.

*I am building a manager node that enables "layer like" management of nodes zPosition, essentially enabling you to get rid of the manual management of the zPosition property and instead to add nodes with methods like `addNodeUnder(node:SKNode)` and also to create groups.*

Here is a test scene I have made :
[image: We can see a blue node, itself under a green node, itself under a yellow node, itself under a red node.]

The problem is that with the operations I have made, the green and the yellow node should be **on top** of the red node.

I made my own little debugger, displaying the SceneKit "scene graph" in hierarchical order :

```
Node of type LMManagerNode  has zPosition = 0.0 and has children :
           Node of type LMWarpperNode  has zPosition = 0.0 and has children :
                     Node of type SKSpriteNode ('Red node') has zPosition = 0.0.

           Node of type LMWarpperNode  has zPosition = -100.0 and has children :
                     Node of type SKSpriteNode ('Blue node') has zPosition = 0.0.

           Node of type LMWarpperNode  has zPosition = 100.0 and has children :
                     Node of type LMGroupNode ('Test group') has zPosition = 0.0 and has children :
                               Node of type LMWarpperNode  has zPosition = -150.0 and has children :
                                         Node of type SKSpriteNode ('Yellow node') has zPosition = 0.0.

                               Node of type LMWarpperNode  has zPosition = -200.0 and has children :
                                         Node of type SKSpriteNode ('Green node') has zPosition = 0.0.
```

As you can see :

- The red node is contained inside a node that has `zPosition = 0`
- The blue node is contained inside a node that has `zPosition = -100`
- The yellow and green nodes are contained inside a group node, itself contained inside a node that has `zPosition = 100`

Since the node that contains the red node has `zPosition = 0` and the node that contains the green and yellow nodes has `zPosition = 100`, shouldn't these two nodes be **on top** of the red node ?

*The `ignoresSiblingOrder` of my `SKView` is set to `false` by the way...*

EDIT : That's weird : yellowNode.zPosition = 1000 does make the yellow node go on top of the red node. How can it be possible ?

EDIT #2 Here is the code of my debugging function :

```
func renderNodeHieararchyForNode(node:SKNode, index:Int) {

    var i = 0
    var beginning = ""
    while i != index {
        beginning += "          "
        i++
        if i == index {
            beginning += " "
        }
    }

    print("\(beginning)Node of type \(node.dynamicType) \(node.name != nil ? "('\(node.name!)')" : "") has zPosition = \(node.zPosition)\(node.children.count > 0 ? " and has children :" : ".")")
    for (i,child) in node.children.enumerate() {
        renderNodeHieararchyForNode(child, index: index+1)

        if i == node.children.count-1 {
            print("")
        }
    }

}

func renderNodeHiearchyForNode(node:SKNode) {
    renderNodeHieararchyForNode(node, index: 0)
}
```

As you can see, I use only the SpriteKit framework methods to display it, so the output of my debugger is definitely correct.

Comment: I believe things got changed, and the nodes inside the parent nodes no longer respect the zPosition in some way,  did you try setting the yellow and green nodes zPosition and not the parents zPosition, and see if it comes on top?

Comment: That's wired : `yellowNode.zPosition = 1000` does make the yellow node go on top of the red node. How can it be possible ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: You should show use your code.

Comment: @appzYourLife Unfortunately, I don't have the right to.  But however, whatever is the code, when I do display the scene graph hierarchy, there is no other instruction after that.

Comment: @appzYourLife But here is my debugging function, in the edit of my post.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Sorry, I forgot to mention you in my comment.

Comment: Answer?  you mean comment,  I am currently typing up an answer for you

Comment: I suggest you read the section entitled [Understanding the Drawing Order for a Node Tree](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes, thank you.

Comment: @TrevorAnneDenise It would be easier for everybody if you could make an example which can reproduce what you are saying, just by using regular SKNode and SKSpriteNodes. It's easier to test, and we don't have to guess anything then...You know, we copy/paste, find a problem, and you get an answer faster like that.

Comment: @Whirlwind I am aware that it generally helps, but as I said, I can't post it.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise Yeah, I understood that, I just meant that you are allowed to mimic the issue with regular SKNode as a container node, and SKSpriteNode for the sprites instead of using the real code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you are expecting your code right now

```
 -100: Node
     # 0: Node
        # 0: Blue
   0 : Node
     # 0: Node
        # 0:Red
 100 : Node
     # 0: Node
        # -200:Green
        # -150:Yellow
```

But what is really happening is this

```
 -100: Node
     : Node
     : Blue
     : Green
 -50 : Yellow
   0 : Node
     : Node
     : Red
 100 : Node
     : Node
```

This is because the zPosition is just subtracted from the parent, and the screen then draws in 1 pass all the nodes.

To combat this, you  need to create a custom class that overrides the `addChild` function and do somethings that keep track of your `zPosition` in another variable (probably a dictionary), then set the child zPosition to zero, and use `insertChild(node:, atIndex:)` to place your children in order in the children array using this new variable to preserve your order. Then if you are going even more crazy, you would have to keep track of when a child changes its zPosition, and use the above style to set it correctly in the array

Comment: Oh thank you so much for your answer! That's a wired behaviour IMO... but that's justified by performance reasons.

Comment: Actually, I am already using dictionaries as their computational cost doesn't increase proportionally to the number of nodes in the scene. I think I'll use it to calculate the zPositions I should give to the children.

Answer (score 5):

From Apple's documentation,

> The z position is the node’s height relative to its parent node, much as a node’s position property represents its x and y position relative to parent’s position. So you use the z position to place a node above or below the parent’s position.

and

> When you take z positions into account, here is how the node tree is
> rendered:
>
> 1. Each node’s global z position is calculated.
> 2. Nodes are drawn in order from smallest z value to largest z value.
> 3. If two nodes share the same z value, ancestors are rendered first, and siblings are rendered in child order.

where

```
node's global z position = node's z position + node's parent's z position + node's parent's parent's z position + ...
```

With this formula, the global z positions of your nodes are

```
red is 0        (0 + 0 + 0)
blue is -100    (0 + -100 + 0)
yellow = -50    (-150 + 0 + 100 + 0)
green = -100    (-200 + 0 + 100 + 0)
```

From highest to lowest global z position (based on rules 1 and 2), the order in which the nodes appear in the scene is

```
red
yellow
green / blue
```

where red appears on top of yellow and yellow is on top of green/blue. Since green and blue have the same global z value, sibling order (rule 3) is used to determine the drawing order. In this case, green's top-level `LMWarpperNode` node (i.e., its great grandparent) was added to the `LMManagerNode` node after blue's `LMWarpperNode` node, so blue is drawn first and green is drawn over blue.

Here's the final (reversed) draw order

```
red                0
yellow           -50
green           -100
blue            -100 (parent was added to scene before green's great grandparent)
```